# Registration-less Accounts (PHP/Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Im looking for a way to let users browse my website, but I want them  to be able to explore the site before they register. Actually, I wan't them to be able to **use** the site for a certain time.(or indefenitly) So I was thinking I could maybe use cookies in some way to accomplish this, but I am not allowed to use a "SuperCookie" or "Evercookie" so that is not an option.

I was wondering if anyone here could point me in some direction or maybe explain an alternative, or even tell me that thats not going to happen.

What ever you say, I'll be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really enough information in the question to provide a meaningful answer. With your authentication method (what's wrong with a standard session cookie?), have a way of identifying visitors such that they're "authenticated and logged in", "visitor", etc, and let them do certain things based on their permission level at the time ?

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html there is all you need.

Comment: What is there not to get? I want people to be able to use my website without having to sign up, confirm password, open mailbox, check spam folder, click the link, then log in again. I want them to be able to use the website right from the start so the costumer has a reason to sign up in the first place.